# using bulit-in bouncy castle library on android

Tags: android, sdk, certificate

I'm now work on creating PKCS#10 CSR on android.

However, the following class cannot be compiled on eclipse IDE with Android sdk10
(the code below work fine for bouncy castle 1.47 with PC)

I feel that my android SDK does not include bouncy castle library

because the function 'PKCS10CertificationRequest' isn't recognized

```
public class PKCS10Generater
{
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateRequest(
        KeyPair pair)
        throws Exception

        {           
         return new PKCS10CertificationRequest(
                 "SHA256withRSA",
                 new X500Principal("CN=Test CA Certificate"),
                 //new X500Principal("CN=end"),
                 pair.getPublic(),
                 null,
                 pair.getPrivate());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in Bouncy castle libraries in Android. I you need to use Bouncy castle you have to include the libraries.

There are some build in crypto libraries so the best is proably if you can use them instead.
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html